# Why do I get 'no route matches', for a route that exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the error:

`No route matches {:action=>"send_to_client", :controller=>"stages"}`

It corresponds to this line:

```
<%= link_to "<span class='icon send-to-client-icon' title='Send to Client' id='send-to-client'> </span>".html_safe, send_to_client_stage_path(@stage), :id => stage.id, :confirm => "This will send #{stage.name.capitalize} to #{stage.client.email}. Are you sure you are ready?" %>
```

In this `_show_table.html.erb`

```
<%

if @upload != nil
    stage = @upload.stage
end

%>
<h1 class="panel-header">Images</h1>

<% if stage == nil %>
    <div class="images_menu">
        <%= link_to "<span class='icon send-to-client-icon' title='Send to Client' id='send-to-client'> </span>".html_safe, send_to_client_stage_path(@stage), :id => stage.id, :confirm => "This will send #{stage.name.capitalize} to #{stage.client.email}. Are you sure you are ready?" %>      
        <span class="icon compare-icon" data-url="<%= compare_stage_path(stage)%>" title="Compare Images" id="compare-images"> </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
resources :stages do
    member do
      get :step
      get :compare
      get :send_to_client
    end
  end
```

The issue is that this partial `_show_table.html.erb` is in the view folder of my `uploads` model...not the `stages` model.

When I execute that `link_to` in the `stages` model, it works fine. Once I take it out into the `uploads` model it throws that error.

Why would that be the case ?

Edit1: Here is the `send_to_client` action of the `stages` controller:

```
def send_to_client
        stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
        ClientMailer.send_stage(stage).deliver
        if ClientMailer.send_stage(stage).deliver
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully sent to client."
            redirect_to("/")
        else
            flash[:notice] = "There were problems, please try re-sending."
            redirect_to("/")
        end
    end
```

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see all the available routes you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails will raise an ActionController::RoutingError if you use `send_to_client_stage_path(nil)`.

You're mixing up `@stage` and `stage`. If you don't define `@stage` in the controller action, it will be `nil` and the error raises. In this case, just use `@upload.stage`.

Like:

```
<% if @upload.stage %>
  <%= link_to "...", send_to_client_stage_path(@upload.stage), :confirm => "..." %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to use `@stage`, just define it in the action with `@stage = @upload.stage` and use it instead of `@upload.stage`:

```
<% if @stage %>
  <%= link_to "...", send_to_client_stage_path(@stage), :confirm => "..." %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should probably be

```
send_to_client_stage_path(stage)
```

instead of

```
send_to_client_stage_path(@stage)
```

And it should be "unless", not "if" here, right?

```
<% unless stage.nil? %>
```

Also, dont forget you can use "unless", it's nicer sometimes

```
if @upload != nil
    stage = @upload.stage
end
```

->

```
stage = @upload.stage unless @upload.nil?
```

Comment: Those changes still don't help me. I am still getting the routing error.

Comment: The routing error is because it is a member route, and therefore needs an id. If the stage is nil, it won't have an id.

Comment: @Austin, so how do I handle that ? As is now, if I set it as `unless stage.nil?` it doesn't execute, but when I do `unless !stage.nil?` it throws that Routing Error. Basically I want it to show that link if a stage.id exists (i.e. not nil). If it doesn't exist, then I don't want the link shown.

Comment: @marcamillion Not showing the link, and it not executing, are the same thing, are they not? Perhaps you need set up the data in your test so that the stage is not nil?